# How should i create logic for checkout page for an e-commerce website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am using React and building a simple e-commerce project. On the shop page, when I click a product's "+" button, that product will be added to the checkout items. The issue is that if you add more than one of the same product, it will add it as another item. What I want to do is if a product's quantity is greater than 1, then just show 1 item and show the quantity.

I use useContext for share all data to shop and checkout pages. I created the addItem function and all states in that context.(ShopContext)

ShopContext

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
 const [checkoutItems, setCheckoutItems] = useState([]);

const addItem = (id) => {
    const newProduct = id;
    setCheckoutItems([...checkoutItems, products[newProduct]]);
  };

 const values = {
    products,
    addItem,
    checkoutItems,
  };
  return (
    <ShopContext.Provider value={values}>{props.children}</ShopContext.Provider>
  );
```

The button:

```
<button
              id={idx}
              className="bg-purple-400 px-4"
              onClick={(e) => addItem(e.target.id)}>+</button>
```

Checkout Page

```
const Checkout = () => {
  const { checkoutItems } = useContext(ShopContext);
  return (
    <div className="my-7 lg:max-w-7xl mx-auto font-Rubik items-center">
      {JSON.stringify(checkoutItems)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your checkoutItems should be an array of objects with properties like

```
[ { id: 'abc', quantity: 2 }, { id: 'cde', quantity: 1 ]
```

On backend you should retrieve the price of the product base on ID and display it to the user. You don't need more information (such as price etc.) in your frontend because all of this should be handled by backend. You also don't want to have any endpoint on your server which will allow information such as price to be sent by frontend.

Comment: I'm using fakeStoreAPI (https://fakestoreapi.com/docs). This API has `count` property but I don't want to use it so is there another way to check the quantites of products?